# ISBLANK Help Needed

Tags: google-sheets

I need some help with Google Spreadsheets on a document. I want to see if there is (any) value in a certain cell in an external document but I want to do it on a larger scale as in 11 different cells.

I have it so it will paste at least one (with all the code) but I need it to run the code for all of them on one cell. The code I have so far is:

`=IF(ISBLANK(Attendance!$C10:$M$10), "GR", 
IF(ISBLANK(Attendance!$D$10:$M$10), "MG", 
IF(ISBLANK(Attendance!$E$10:$M$10), "PM", 
IF(ISBLANK(Attendance!$F$10:$M$10), "GD", 
IF(ISBLANK(Attendance!$G$10:$M$10), "MK", 
IF(ISBLANK(Attendance!$H$10:$M$10), "CE", 
IF(ISBLANK(Attendance!$I$10:$M$10), "PI", 
IF(ISBLANK(Attendance!$K$10:$M$10), "SL", 
IF(ISBLANK(Attendance!$L$10:$M$10), "BC", 
IF(ISBLANK(Attendance!$M$10), "IN"))))))))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the following was found suitable:

```
 =if(isblank(C10)," GR","")&if(isblank(D10)," MG","")&if(isblank(E10)," PM","")&if(isblank(F10)," GD","")&if(isblank(G10)," MK","")&if(isblank(H10)," CE","")&if(isblank(I10)," PI","")&if(isblank(J10)," aa","")&if(isblank(K10)," SL","")&if(isblank(L10)," BC","")&if(isblank(M10)," IN","")
```

Comment: This worked for my project. I give many thanks to you for helping me through this. (Marked as answer)

Answer (score 0):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=VLOOKUP(COUNTA(C10:M10),{1,"GR";2,"MG";3,"PM";4,"GD";5,"MK";6,"CE";7,"PI";8,"SL";9,"BC";10,"IN";11,""},2,0)`

If not, please share some sample data and the expected result

Comment: It does not work as how I wanted it to work. Thank you for trying to help though. I got my answer from @pnuts.